# Tomcat's resource name JNDI-style

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, websphere, jndi

I'm moving a really huge `Websphere 9` application to `Tomcat 9`.

Everything in the app works fine, except one thing.

The app used a `WorkManagerTaskExecutor` through a wired bean:

```
@Bean
public WorkManagerTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    WorkManagerTaskExecutor  pool = new WorkManagerTaskExecutor();
    pool.setWorkManagerName("someName");
    //pool.setResourceRef(true);
    return pool;
}
```

In Websphere there was probably some resource configured through the management console.

In `Tomcat`, I've created a `Resource` in `server.xml`:

```
<Resource name = "someName"
              auth = "Container"
              type = "commonj.work.WorkManager"
              factory = "de.myfoo.commonj.work.FooWorkManagerFactory"
              minThreads = "1"
              maxThreads = "25" />
```

and a link in `context.xml`:

```
<ResourceLink name="someName" global="someName" type="commonj.work.WorkManager" />
```

And the error:

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [someName] is not bound in
>   this Context.

Now, if I enable this line:

```
pool.setResourceRef(true);
```

It works perfectly but I don't want to make any modifications in the code.

I've already tried renaming both .xml configs's variables to JNDI-style because [JndiLocatorSupport documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jndi/JndiLocatorSupport.html#setResourceRef-boolean-) says:

```
If the name doesn't begin with "java:comp/env/", this prefix is added if "resourceRef" is set to "true".
```

But `name="java:comp/env/someName"` doesn't work either.
Is this even possible to overcome? What the name should be?

Comment: Did you get answer. I have same query. Also what you have written in de.myfoo.commonj.work.FooWorkManagerFactory

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me!

1. applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="scheduler"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <!-- Refer your trigger beans -->
                <ref bean="cronDeleteSynchronizationTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="schedulerDataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:quartz.properties" />
        <property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutor" />
</bean>
<bean id="taskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor">
    <property name="workManagerName" value="java:comp/env/wm/someName" />   
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
</bean>
```

2. In Context.xml

```
<Context>
    <Resource name = "wm/someName"
              auth = "Container"
              type = "commonj.work.WorkManager"
              factory = "de.myfoo.commonj.work.FooWorkManagerFactory"
              minThreads = "1"
              maxThreads = "5" 
            />
</Context>
```

3)I also added jars like

```
   commonj-1.1.0.jar
   aktivecortex-foo-commonj-1.3.0.jar
   slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
```